# how to identify checkbox only checked dynamically create knockout

Tags: knockout.js

i tried to identify dynamically create check box using this code.when i checked check box it give correct value but i checked 2 check box and unchecked one but cant identify what i checked or not....

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: customers" id="tbody_tr">
    @*   <tr style="border: solid" data-bind="click: $root.setSelectedUser" id="updtr">*@
        <tr style="border: solid" id="updtr">
           <td><input class="userckselectedbox" type="checkbox" data-bind="event:{checked: $root.selectedUserNames }" /></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: ID"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text:Dateofbirth"></span></td>  
            <td><label data-bind="click:$root.setSelectedUser">ok</label></td>                          
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

**strong text**

```
self.selectedUserNames = function getdata(user)
        {

            alert(user.Name);
        }
```

Comment: ok... when i checked check box in my table i want pop up data only for  particular check box. but problem is firstly i checked 1st check box and i can pop data and again i checked 2 rd check box and i can popup data again i unchecked 2 check box.how to identify 1 st check box checked or nor???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a fiddle according to your requirement. Check this:

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/opefip/1/edit).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Very nice example, it helped me out and got me understanding Knockout a bit better. Thanks.